# Calling pickle method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

Im having a bit of trouble outputing 2 functions I created on my program.
I have the following dictionary:

```
def game():
    return {
    'players': [],
    'active_players':[],
    'running_game': False,
```

I gather the data from here:

```
def player_register(mm,name):
    board1_for_ship_placement = create_grid(columns_size,rows_size)
    board2_for_showing = create_grid(columns_size,rows_size)
    player = {
        'name':name,
        'played_games': 0,
        'victory': 0,
        'ships_available' : {
            "speeder":0,
            "sub":0,
            "frag":0,
            "cruz":0,
        "spaceship":0
        },
        'ships_in_use':[],
        'board1': board1_for_ship_placement,
        'board2': board2_for_showing
    }
    mm['players'].append(player)
```

Then I created 2 function to save and load:

```
def save():
    my_dict = game()
    with open("my_data.pkl", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(my_dict, f)

def load():
    with open("my_data.pkl", "rb") as f:
    my_data = pickle.load(f)
```

This is my menu function:

```
def main():
    mm = fun.game()
    letters_dict = fun.dict_letters()
    ships_size = fun.check_ships_size()
    while True:
        line = input("Insert Comand: ")
        if not line: # checks if input is empty line , if so
            break # it breaks out of while loop
        commands = line.split(" ")
        elif commands[0] == "G":
            commandG(commands,fun)
        elif commands[0] == "L":
            commandL(commands,fun)
        elif commands[0] == "teste":
            print(mm['jogadores_em_ativo'])
        elif commands[0] == "break":
            break
```

I built this 2 functions (one for loading and one for saving):

```
def commandG(commands,fun):
    dados = pickle.dump(game())
    print("Game Saved")

def commandL(commands,fun):
    dados = pickle.loads(game())
    print("Game Loaded")
```

But it's not working...Am I missing up something? How can I make the program save and load data by pressing G or L?

Comment: "it's not working" is not specific enough. Please describe the issue: are you getting errors? does your computer blow up? _how_ is it "not working"?

Comment: @Carcigenicate it just closes the program and does nothing.

Comment: @ForceBru Simply closing the program and not saving the data as I intended.

Comment: @motspeed, what's your input? Place `print(repri(line))` after `line = input("Insert Comand: ")`, run your code and show the input and the output

Comment: @motspeed What are you doing with the pickled data? Are you saving it anywhere?

Comment: Also, `elif commands[0] == "G":` is a syntax error because it attempts to start a new `if/elif/else` statement with `elif`

Comment: @ForceBru I have more functions that I did not copy here not to clutter but Imagine I have RP A, It registers a player A and outputs, "Registered Player". Then I want to save the player to a list and press G and I get the error:  name 'game' is not defined.

Comment: It's very difficult to say without seeing your code but it sounds like your def statement for your game function is not yet defined when it comes to this part of your code. It also looks like there are a few other things wrong here but like I mentioned, it's difficult to say without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: @Axe319 Here is my complete code: https://codeshare.io/G7jWR1 and https://codeshare.io/5Nqxn1 It's in my main language but I think you can understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your problem is I think a misunderstanding of what pickle does and is intended for.

It can be used to preserve a save state, just not the way you're doing it.

Lets start with the error you're getting. There is no game function defined in the file your python file that you are calling it from. So you cant use `game()`. You would need to call it with `fun.game()`.

Secondly, your game function is returning a dict with some empty list values and some False values so this is not the state you want to preserve anyway.

Finally, what pickle is intended for is serializing python objects such as dicts into bytes. The reason you'd want to do that is because you can then transfer those bytes over a socket or save them to a text file.

To load that saved dict or object you would then need to read the text file or receive the byte string through a socket and unpickle and voila, you have an object.

To test it and help you see how it works, hop into the python console and run these commands.

```
import pickle
test = {'test':69}
print(test)
pickled = pickle.dumps(test)
print(pickled)
```

Notice how your object is now just text?

```
with open('file.txt', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(pickled)
```

Now open the test.txt file and see how it saved it?

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as file:
    file_data = file.read()
```

Now we've retrieved our pickled dict so we need to unpickle it.

```
unpickled = pickle.loads(file_data)
print(unpickled)
```

Hopefully this is clear.

If you really want this to save your dict. Which, to be fair I only skimmed your code, but it looks like your data is in a dict named `mm`.

Try this with your save and load functions.

```
def commandG(mm):
    with open("my_data.pkl", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(mm, f)

def commandL():
    with open("my_data.pkl", "rb") as f:
        mm = pickle.load(f)
    return mm
```

And call them like this.

```
commandG(mm)

mm = commandL()
```

You'll also need to  `import pickle` in this python file

Comment: Yeah I get it, I even tried to open the file on notepad and it kinda looks encripted.But I get it how it works on a simple dictionary like that. Im having trouble getting the data out of the game() method. Even after renaming game() to fun.game() Im getting the error dump() missing required argument 'file' (pos 2)

Comment: Try `dumps` rather that `dump`.

Comment: Seems to work fine, at least I get no error. But wasn't it not supposed to create a file in the folder? It didn't create anything. Can't really know because when I try the load method Im getting: "file must have 'read' and 'readline' atributes. I tried either dados = pickle.load(fun.game()) and dados = pickle.loads(fun.game())

Comment: So as I mentioned above `loads` and `dumps` only pickles and unpickles. `load` unpickles data from an open file. `dump` writes pickled data to an open file.

`pickle.loads(fun.game())` will do nothing because the dict you're handing it is already a dict and unpickled.

Comment: @motspeed I've modified my answer a bit.

Comment: I have modified the save and load like you said. Im not understanding the save(mm) and mm = load(). Where should I place those?Because Im calling them on my save and load methods (with pickle.dump and pickle.load.

Comment: I just noticed you have them written in your code as `commandG` and `commandL`. I'll modify my comment accordingly.

Comment: I did that (https://codeshare.io/G7jWR1) line 161 and 164 and when pressing G I get name mm is not defined. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: No problem. https://codeshare.io/G7jWR1 This is what I meant by calling them differently.

Comment: Nvm, my error! It's working now, finally! I cannot thank you enough man, thanks for your help.

Comment: One last thing, would be an easy way to display a message like "Save Successful" if it saved and "Error Saving" if it failed?

Comment: Just printing works. You could put it into a try / except block and have it print "Error Saving" inside the except.